# In R: use system() to pass python command with white spaces

Tags: python, r, system, whitespace, argument-passing

Im trying to pass a python command from R (on Windows x64 Rstudio) to a python script via the command promt. It works if I type directly into cdm but not if I do it via R using the R function `system()`. The format is (this is how I EXACTLY would write in the windows cmd shell/promt):

```
pyhton C:/some/path/script <C:/some/input.file> C:/some/output.file
```

This works in the cmd promt, and runs the script with the input file (in <>) and gives the output file. I thought I in R could do:

```
system('pyhton C:/some/path/script <C:/some/input.file> C:/some/output.file')
```

But this gives an error from python about

```
error: unparsable arguments: ['<C:/some/input.file>', 'C:/some/output.file']
```

It seems as if R or windows interpret the white spaces different than if I simply wrote (or copy-paste) the line to the cmd promt. How to do this.

Comment: can you give the real command to investigate?

Comment: Im trying to get the RWebLogo::weblogo R function to work. It throws from R a python command. Works fine in cmd promt, but I would like to have it work via R (as intended). The script says: Usage: weblogo [options]  < sequence_data.fa > sequence_logo.eps

Comment: Which script says that? on the RWebLogo readme I can see only `weblogo(file.in=fpath, file.out='mylogo_msf.pdf')`. Anyway the input file is after `<` and the output is before the `>`

Comment: Yes but if I run the R function weblogo it throws an error. From this error you can see that it call the weblogo script. If you do this in cmd promt exactly like I write above it works. So I thought to use system() to send the exact same command to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?system`

> This interface has become rather complicated over the years: see
>   system2 for a more portable and flexible interface which is
>   recommended for new code.

System2 accepts a parameter `args` for the arguments of your command.

So you can try:

```
system2('python', c('C:\\some\\path\\script', 'C:\\some\\input.file', 'C:\\some\\output.file'))
```

**On Windows:**

`R` documentation is not really clear on this point (or maybe it's just me), anyway it seems that on Windows the suggested approach is to use the `shell()` which is less raw than `system` and `system2`, plus it seems to work better with [redirection operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) (like < or >).

```
shell ('python C:\\some\\path\\script < C:\\some\\input.file > C:\\some\\output.file')
```

So what is this command doing is:

1. Call python
2. Telling python to execute the script `C:\some\path\script`. Here we need to escape the '\' using '\'.
3. Then we passing some inputs to the script using a the '<' operator and the input.file
4. We redirect the output (using '>') to the output file.

Comment: did you escape the brackets with `\\`?

Comment: If I write like you with <C:\\some\\input.file> (ie. < as is ) R doesnt recognize <: Error: unexpected '<' in "system2. What do you mean with 'escape brackets' then ig not the <'s ?

Comment: I put the < > just because you had it in your original question, I thought you used them just to indicate a placeholder. Just remove them and use the quotation marks

Comment: Ah I see. No the <> need to be there, its part of the argument, they need to "quote" the input file. How do you escape them, or rather: why would you escpae them?

Comment: If I write like in your answer (but with '<C:\\some\\input.file>' - brackets and quotes) it says unparsable arguments: ['<C:/some/input.file>', 'C:/some/output.file'].

Comment: I don't have a python script to test it now, but you can try this `system2('python', c("script.py", "<", "c:\\jdfldjf\\dlfhsid\\kkk.py",">", "c:\\jdfldjf\\dlfhsid\\kkk.py"));`

Comment: Its a good idea. But it stil gives the unusable arguments error - now with the two file paths and also the two > and <. How can it be so problematic to have this written in cmd promt: `pyhton C:/some/path/script <C:/some/input.file> C:/some/output.file` ???

Comment: try to replace "<" with "\074" and ">" with "\040" maybe the octal representation will work

Comment: It can interpret it (">" is "\076"), but it can still not be interpreted in cdm. I wonder if it is the < and > that is the problem. It comes down to how you from R get cmd to execute a line like `pyhton C:/some/path/script <C:/some/input.file> C:/some/output.file`

Comment: I have tried system2 above; unsure how to use shell(); something along shell(python, "C:/some/path/script <C:/some/input.file> C:/some/output.file") wont do it. Basically I dont understand whether its the brackets or white spaces that messing it up.

Comment: looks like on windows system doesn't work and you need to use `shell()`. I have updated my answer with the shell code.

Comment: That was it - it worked! Could you elaborate a little on what was going on here. I tried also system in Rgui and it didnt work either. If it is the Gui/RStudio, would it be worth scripting the R code from command prompt perhaps ?

Comment: Check my last update. I think the gui has nothing to do with your code

Comment: Perfect! With a good explanation though I still dont get why system() fails for  the <>.

Comment: You could start with the help command for sytem, system2 and shell and then you can dig on the R code to figure out the problem